# Convergence of moments of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I encountered this problem in my study of time series. It seemed trivial at first but I don't see the finishing move to complete the proof. The problem is as follows.

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of random variables and $X$ also a random variable on some probability space. Suppose that $E\left[\lvert X_n - X\rvert^p\right]\to 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity and $E\left[\lvert X\rvert^p\right]< \infty$ for some $p \geq 1$. Show that $E[X_n^k] \to E[X^k]$ for every $0<k\leq p$.

We of course know that $E\left[\lvert X_n - X\rvert^p\right]\to 0$ implies $E\left[\lvert X_n - X\rvert^k\right]\to 0$ for every $0<k\leq p$ (by Jensen). By triangle inequality, $E\left[\lvert X_n - X\rvert^k\right]\to 0$ implies $E\left[\lvert X_n \rvert^k\right]\to E\left[\lvert X\rvert^k\right]$. I have not made use of the facts that $E\left[\lvert X\rvert^p\right]< \infty$ and $p\geq 1$ so far. I also find it strange that $k$ is not restricted to positive integers in the statement of the problem (suppose $X = -1$ a.s. and $k$ is irrational.)

Comment: Do we know that $\mathbb{E}[|X|^p]$ is finite? Or that $\sup_n\mathbb{E}[|X_n|^p]<\infty$?

Comment: @carmichael561 The former. There was a typo in my original question. I corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As you said in the question, it's not clear how to make sense of $X_n^k$ for arbitrary $k$ if the $X_n$ take on negative values.

Comment: @carmichael561 If we restrict $k$ to positive integers, do you then have a solution? I haven't thought about this restricted problem so it might be trivial.

Comment: I'd try to break up $X$ and $X_n$ into positive and negative parts in that case.

Comment: @carmichael561 That is the first thing I tried. I couldn't get too far with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from a generalized [dominated convergence theorem](https://books.google.ca/books?id=wI4fAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT52&lpg=PT52&dq=Folland+exercise+2.20&source=bl&ots=m0ck9SAbtN&sig=LIqOEnOkN6Y2XjToF8KmUDrBe0k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCoNng68XMAhUB62MKHY4uAmMQ6AEIUDAI#v=onepage&q=(A%20generalized%20Dominated%20Convergence%20Theorem)&f=false). Let $\zeta_n:=X_n^k$ and $\zeta:=X^k$. Since $\mathbb{E}|\zeta_n|\le c_k[\mathbb{E}|X_n-X|^k+\mathbb{E}|\zeta|]$ and $k\le p$, $\zeta_n\in L^1$ ($\zeta\in L^1$ by assumption). In addition, you've already shown that $\mathbb{E}|\zeta_n|\to\mathbb{E}|\zeta|$. Thus, for any subsequence $n_m$, there is a further subsequence $n_m'$, s.t. $\zeta_{n_m'}\to\zeta$ a.e. and by the DCT

$$\lim\int \zeta_{n_m'}dP=\int \zeta dP$$

Comment: What is $c_k$? Referring to the link that you gave, $f_n =\xi_n$, right? What is $g_n$ that bounds $f_n$ in your solution?

Comment: $c_k$ is a constant depending on $k$, $f_n=\zeta_n$ and $g_n=|\zeta_n|$.

Comment: I think I understand your answer. But do you have an explicit expression for $c_k$?

Comment: This constant is from "$c_r$-inequality", i.e. $c_k=1$ for $0<k\le 1$ and $2^{k-1}$ for $k>1$.

Comment: Thanks. I will go through the solution one more time to make sure I cover all the details.